# Store entity in checkbox

Tags: php, drupal-7

Sorry for asking such a question, Do we have any way to store Entities to Checkboxes ? Because I'm doing a "Tableselect", I want to multi check and I get by each check value is an Entity.

> Ex: I want select 5 rows then I have to delete 5 rows that I have
>   selected, delete function have to run via delete entity API:

- Old way, get list Id select,  make an SQL query then execute the query.
- New way: Get list Entity, delete data by delete API <---  That is what I want to know, do we have this way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the answer after few minutes....quite easy, just use **entity_load**

```
$results = <List ID checkbox>;
foreach ($results as $var) {
     $entity = entity_load('entity_example_basic', array ($var));
 // Do sth....
}
```